# Unsecure FTP with Encrypted file and Wireshark leakage

Tags: encryption, gnupg, data-leakage, sniffer, wireshark

Hi i was wandering if it is possible to have a password leaked to an encrypted file on an anon ftp server with r-x-w permissions.

So for example i have a file encrypted using gpg and when opened on the server i input my password would wireshark leak to password used? i know the data coming back would require a key to view, but would the password be leaked as its an unsercure FTP server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot open a remote file with GPG through FTP. Instead you would need to download the file to the local system and open it there. Because of this the decryption will be done only locally (and will be independent from that way the file arrived on the local system) and thus password for the file will thus stay local too.